# How to execute redis cache INFO command from java code

Tags: redis

I should get all the stats about Redis by using getStatistics() method in java?

public ArrayList getStatistics(){
}

The above method should return all the stats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Spring Data Redis, you can do this

> ```
> Properties info = redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().info();
> ```